# Creating Newlines in PDF with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, newline

I have an application which creates a list from items in a collection. Then for each item, I will add it to an empty string, then add a newline character to the end of it. So ideally my string will look something like:

List1\nList2\nList3\n

Once this string is generated, I send it back to be placed in a placeholder for a pdf. If I try this code in a simple console application, it prints everything on a newline. But in my real world situation, I have to print it to a pdf. The items only show up with spaces in between them and not newlines. How can can format my strings so that pdf recognizes the newline symbol rather than ignoring it?

Here is my code that generates the string with newlines.

```
    Private Function ConcatPlacardNumbers(ByVal BusinessPlacardCollection As BusinessPlacardCollection) As String
    Dim PlacardNumbersList As String = Nothing
    Dim numberofBusinessPlacards As Long = BusinessPlacardCollection.LongCount()
    For Each BusinessPlacard As BusinessPlacard In BusinessPlacardCollection
        numberofBusinessPlacards = numberofBusinessPlacards - 1
        PlacardNumbersList = String.Concat(PlacardNumbersList, BusinessPlacard.PlacardNumber)
        If numberofBusinessPlacards <> 0 Then
            PlacardNumbersList = String.Concat(PlacardNumbersList, Enviornment.newline)
        End If
    Next
    Return PlacardNumbersList
End Function
```

Comment: What component or tool are you using to generate the PDF?

Comment: I'm not fully sure since it's a large scale application, but there appears to be a class called DocumentGenerationManager with a method GenerateDocument() which then uses a DataMerger to merge all the data. I'm still trying to learn how everything works in the application since I am fairly new to the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `\u2028` instead:

```
Private Function ConcatPlacardNumbers(ByVal BusinessPlacardCollection As _
                                      BusinessPlacardCollection) As String

    Dim PlacardNumbersList As New StringBuilder()

    For Each BusinessPlacard As BusinessPlacard In BusinessPlacardCollection

        PlacardNumbersList.Append(BusinessPlacard.PlacardNumber)
        'PlacardNumbersList.Append(ChrW(8232)) '\u2028 line in decimal form
        PlacardNumbersList.Append(ChrW(8233)) '\u2029 paragr. in decimal form

    Next

    Return PlacardNumbersList.ToString

End Function
```

For paragraphs use `\u2029`instead. Fore more details:
http://blogs.adobe.com/formfeed/2009/01/paragraph_breaks_in_plain_text.html

Comment: Thanks, I think this might be my solution. But VB.Net doesn't use forward slashes or better yet, recognize them. So what's the equivalent in VB.net for \u2029? This would work in C#.

Comment: ay, you're right. Just convert the two bytes represented as hexadecimals to numbers. I updated my answer with the equivalent as decimal number.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on the tool that is being used to produce the PDF. Since newline doesn't work, I would actually try `\n`. The other possibility is that the PDF generation code is not designed to emit multiple lines; you can only determine this by examining the generation code.

However, there is a significant performance issue that you should address in your code: you will be generating a lot of string objects using this code. You should change the design to use [System.Text.StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx), which will greatly improve the performance:

```
Private Function ConcatPlacardNumbers(ByVal BusinessPlacardCollection As BusinessPlacardCollection) As String
    Dim PlacardNumbersList As New System.Text.StringBuilder(10000)
    For Each BusinessPlacard As BusinessPlacard In BusinessPlacardCollection
        If PlacardNumbersList.Length <> 0 Then
            ' This is equivalent to Environment.NewLine
            'PlacardNumbersList.AppendLine()
            ' The attempt to use \n
            PlacardNumbersList.Append("\n")
        End If
        PlacardNumbersList.Append(BusinessPlacard.PlacardNumber)
    Next
    Return PlacardNumbersList.ToString
End Function
```

Note that you also do not need to keep track of the placard number: you can add a newline to the end of the previous item on each pass after the first one.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good point with the performance. Using what you have above, the output is:

"ABCNNN\nABCMMM\nABCVVV\n"

If I used Enviornment.Newline it would be:

"ABCNNN ABCMMM ABCVVV"

So this still doesn't give me a newline. But I understand that it all depends on the application that generates the pdf and how it handles the pdf. I might need to consult with my colleagues on this one to see the background on the pdf generation tool they are using.

Comment: I added the \n as an option to try in case the code actually producing the PDFs is looking for this instead of CrLf. It's worth a try to see if it works.